# Problems with Textfields after upgrading to Xcode 15.0

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

I'm wondering if someone can tell me why since updating to Xcode 15.0 I am having a problem with Textfields under certain circumstances. And how I can fix it.

It’s difficult to explain. I’ve provided a simple example that demonstrates the issue. I’m running macOS Sonoma Ver 14.0. In the example when you open the sheet and enter a price, it only excepts the first number you enter then all other numbers are added to the end of the double value.

Eg. Default value is 0.00.
When you type 1.55. The value is changed to 1.0055. It completes the double value after the first number is typed and anything else is appended to the end.
You can also just highlight the decimal portion (00) and the same thing happens. If the default value is again 0.00. and you type 55. The value is changed to 0.505

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var decimals = Decimals()
    @StateObject var priceVM = Price.ViewModel()
    @State var enterSelected = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                enterSelected = true
            }) {
                Text("Enter Price")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $enterSelected) {
                Price(decimals: decimals, viewModel: priceVM)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Price: View {
    @ObservedObject var decimals: Decimals
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: Price.ViewModel
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Price = \(viewModel.price)")
        }
        .frame(width: 400 ,height: 200)
        .background(.white)
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Price:", value: $viewModel.price, formatter: decimals.decimalPlaces())
                    .frame(width: 95)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding(3)
            }
        }
        VStack {
            Button("Close") {
                dismiss()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 11)
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
        }
    }
}

extension Price {
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var price: Double = 0.0
    }
}

class Decimals: ObservableObject {
    func decimalPlaces(_ minimum: Int = 2, _ maximum: Int = 11) -> NumberFormatter {
        let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = minimum
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = maximum
            return formatter
        }()
        
        return formatter
    }
}
```

Prior to updating Xcode, this worked just fine.

If I create the Price view model in the actual Price view as you would usually do then there are no issues. It works fine. However, in the app I’m working on, the price value is contained within a method that displays this value in a parent view and I am creating the Price view Model in that parent view and passing it to the Price view in order for the state change to be observed.

I’ve included the custom NumberFormatter I’m using just in case this is part of the problem, but I don’t think it is.

The app is a lot more detailed than this so I've simplified it down to isolate the issue.

Comment: Why is Decimals an ObservableObject? There is nothing to observe. Just put it inside an extension or some other non-reference place.

Comment: try removing the objects you shouldnt have view model objects in SwiftUI

Comment: In the simplified example here, Window does nothing but contain the decimalPlaces() method so is therefore not necessary here. In the working code, it does much more. I have included it here just to show that the TextField is formatted that way. Other than that it can be ignored.